# Is Django login redirect stripping my url parameters?

Tags: python, django, url-parameters

In my URLconf I have the following url (where `login` is the built-in login view function from `django.contrib.auth.views`):

```
url(r'^login/', login, name='login', kwargs={
    'template_name': 'topspots/login.html',
    'redirect_field_name': 'next',
})
```

Then in my template, in a navbar that is present on all pages on the site, I have the following login link:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.get_full_path }}">Log in</a></li>
```

When I visit the login page from, e.g., the search results page, the url I get in the address bar is something like:

```
http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/spots/search/?search_query=South+Oak+Park%2C+KCMO%2C+MO%2C+United+States&searchtype=default&latitude=38.97600750000001&longitude=-94.58623399999999
```

which seems right to me (note the `longitude` and `latitude` parameters), because after logging in, I would like to be redirected to

```
http://localhost:8000/spots/search/?search_query=South+Oak+Park%2C+KCMO%2C+MO%2C+United+States&searchtype=default&latitude=38.97600750000001&longitude=-94.58623399999999
```

i.e., the `next` path. However, from the login view, the value of `{{ next }}` ends up being `/spots/search/?search_query=South Oak Park, KCMO, MO, United States`. In other words, all the parameters except for the first one have been stripped. I have not been able to figure when/where/why these parameters are getting chopped off. Is this something Django is doing, or does it stem from a mistake of mine? If it is Django, I am sure there is a good reason for it, but if it is just me doing something wrong, I would like to fix it. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens is that your generated url ends up being parsed like so:

```
next=/spots/search/?search_query=South+Oak+Park%2C+KCMO%2C+MO%2C+United+States
searchtype=default
latitude=38.97600750000001
longitude=-94.58623399999999
```

The additional parameters are no longer part of the `next` url, so they get dropped. To avoid this, encode the entire url so it stays together:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}">Log in</a></li>
```

The `&` character gets encoded so the browser no longer splits the parameters and sends them to the wrong url.

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode).

Comment: Yes! I can't believe it was something so simple! This probably should have been something I could have found on my own, but when working with an unfamiliar technology, I often find I don't even know where to look or the right questions to ask. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!